# Given an array of N integers, return the max sum of 3 NON-adjacent elements

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-programming

I got this question for a coding interview (mock, part of my uni's competitive programming club since a few people are curious lol), and I got stuck on finding the optimal solution. Extra details/constraints:

- minimum array has to be 5 (because the elements at index 0,2,4 summed would be the answer)

And some examples:
Example test:   [8, -4, -7, -5, -5, -4, 8, 8]
expected 12 because at indices 0, 5, 7, max sum is 8 + -4 + 8 = 12)

Example test:   [-2, -8, 1, 5, -8, 4, 7, 6]
expected 15 b/c at indices 3,5,7, the max sum is 15)

Example test:   [-3, 0, -6, -7, -9, -5, -2, -6]
expected -9 b/c at indices 1,3,6, the max sum is -9)

Example test:   [-10, -10, -10, -10, -10]
expected -30 b/c at indices 1,3,5, max sum is -30)

Here's my current brute force solution:

```
def solution(A):
    # Implement your solution here
    # res = []
    max_sum = -float('inf')
    n = len(A)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 2, n):
            for k in range(j + 2, n):
                temp_sum = A[i] + A[j] + A[k]
                if temp_sum >= max_sum:
                    max_sum = temp_sum
                    # res = [i, j, k]
    return max_sum
```

Is there anything more optimal and efficient?

Comment: What determines the indices to be added?

Comment: whatever indices produces the maximum sum. In the examples provided, those specific 3 indices (there has to be 3), produce the largest possible sum in the array

Comment: So it is the sum of the 3 biggest numbers that aren't adjacent to each other?

Comment: @cup yes. that is correct. you can see the examples and my original imp for ref

Comment: Are there a limits for N and the range of the integers? Is this online somewhere for testing?

Comment: No lower limits for N though you have to throw some sort of error for inputs that won't work (I realized several hours later after reading some of the responses that len(array)< 5 won't work) and the upper limits is on the order of magnitude of like a 100 mil or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem in O(n), being n the size of the array.

The idea is to use Dynamic Programming to save the following information:

1 - What is the best you can make using the first `i` elements, if you were to pick exactly 1 element.
2 - What is the best you can make using the first `i` elements, if you were to pick exactly 2 elements.
3 - What is the best you can make using the first `i` elements, if you were to pick exactly 3 elements.

To answer 1, the best you can make using the first `i` elements is the maximum element from the first `i` elements.

Let's use a matrix to store that information.

Let `dp[1][i]` be the best you can get picking exactly 1 element from the first `i` elements.

To answer 2, the best you can make using the first `i` elements picking 2 elements is:

- Either you do not pick the current `i`-th element, and get the best you could get picking exactly 2 elements up until the `i-1`-th element.
- Or you pick the current `i`-th element and the best you could get picking ONLY 1 element up until the `i-2`-th element.

Let `dp[2][i]` be the best you can get picking exactly 2 elements from the first `i` elements.

It's the maximum of:

- `dp[2][i-1]` (not picking the `i`-th element).
- `A[i] + dp[1][i-2]` (picking the `i`-th plus the best from picking 1 up until the `i-2`-th).

Notice that if you pick the `i`-th, you must NOT pick the `i-1`, as that would violate the rules of the problem.

To answer 3, it's the same as to answer 2:

- Either you do not pick the current `i`-th element, and get the best you could get picking exactly 3 elements up until the `i-1`-th element.
- Or you pick the current `i`-th element and the best you could get picking ONLY 2 elements up until the `i-2`-th element.

The answer will be what lies in `pd[3][n-1]`, which means, the best you could get picking exactly 3 elements from the first `n-1` elements.

The code:

```
def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    
    dp = [[0] * n for i in range(4)]

    dp[1][0] = A[0]          # The best of picking 1 element up to the 1st is the 1st.
    dp[2][0] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 2 elements up to the 1st.
    dp[2][1] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 2 elements up to the 2nd.
    dp[3][0] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 3 elements up to the 1st.
    dp[3][1] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 3 elements up to the 2nd.
                             # Theoretically up to 4th, but the `for` already does it for you.
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        dp[1][i] = max(
                    dp[1][i-1], # Either we skip the current
                    A[i]        # Or we choose it
                    )

    for i in range(2, n):
        dp[2][i] = max(
                    dp[2][i-1],       # Either we skip the current
                    A[i] + dp[1][i-2] # Or we choose it
                    )

    for i in range(2, n):
        dp[3][i] = max(
                    dp[3][i-1],       # Either we skip the current
                    A[i] + dp[2][i-2] # Or we choose it
                    )

    max_sum = dp[3][n-1]
    
    return max_sum
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we have to deal with the **top 7** greatest values, not top 5. The worst case in this regard IMHO is:

```
8 9 8 8 9 8 8
  ^     ^   ^
```

and the max is 9+9+8, but the first four 8's are ruled out because there are adjacent. In general `3*(N-1)+1`.

```
# updated version #2
import heapq
import itertools

def solution(A):

    # extract up to top 7 values and their indices in the original list
    with_indices_gen = zip(A, itertools.count()) # credit: Kelly Bundy
    top_values, top_indices = zip(*heapq.nlargest(7, with_indices_gen))

    # define a tiny helper:
    def is_adjacent(x, y): 
        return abs(top_indices[x] - top_indices[y]) == 1

    # try all valid combinations (worst case 35 loop iterations)
    sums = []
    for i,j,k in itertools.combinations(range(len(top_values)), 3): 
        if is_adjacent(i, j) or is_adjacent(j, k) or is_adjacent(i, k): 
            continue
        sums.append(sum(top_values[x] for x in [i, j, k]))

    # and choose the best
    return max(sums)
```

Comment: @DarkKnight Really? The brute force soln is O(n^3) while this one greatly reduces it to O(nlogn) (due to sorting) or O(7n +35) -> technically O(n) lol.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I did think the soln was very clever tho. Also, did you test the DP soln at the top and its runtime?

Comment: Actually, your code only needs the top *3* for [8,9,8,8,9,8,8]. But it needs the top 7 for [8,8,9,8,8,9,8].

Comment: @DarkKnight  there's no point in measuring performance on a tiny input, unless you expect only tiny inputs. Try it with a list with 10,000 random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

O(N) by combining each middle element with the largest before it (except the one directly before it) and the largest after it (except the one directly after it). Using accumulated prefix/suffix maxima.

```
from itertools import accumulate

def solution(A):
    return max(map(sum, zip(
        accumulate(A, max),
        A[2:],
        [*accumulate(A[:3:-1], max)][::-1]
    )))
```

Benchmark with 10^5 elements:

```
  9.87 ± 0.08 ms  VPfB
 18.15 ± 0.17 ms  Kelly3
 33.67 ± 0.09 ms  Kelly2
 51.42 ± 0.18 ms  Kelly
 87.12 ± 0.55 ms  For

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

`Kelly` is my above solution and `Kelly2` and `Kelly3` are micro-optimized versions replacing `max` and `sum`.

Benchmark script ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVfNbttGEL4LKNBHGCAHkS4lWJSdFERVQAHaSw_NoQhQsISyIpfW2uQuQy5tqUaepJdc0ntfoY_Rp-nM7vJHstMaRnghOZyd-b6Z2Z3hH39WB71T8uPHT63OZ9_-89XXea1K0KLkQoMoK1VryHjO2kJvSFoDa8zniVEUmtdaqaLpdFmatmVbMM0nTtKr2BWNZlo0WqT9kpIzGaA847dWJVVFwVMtlGwGCO_bz7msecWZth9VxWumVd3DybIOx46z6n33UjOZqbJ7aw7NZDJBmvATL4qDt_ajCeBVc93WEkq290pWeU1bBvC7qDzzka6BrbcOSM8P-m_rOIyS4TU-GyvH0TKaLRK7JokjejGqvu-PoYQ9FhKhcuixALZONsK4BZEDg-_wgRcNB_ZMAuFzGIT_RWF5RMGYQDjrEQV8hxXkhWLam86EzKf-Kb24F9Dl0YpoBcy3rL83JgxvfDhSzbEWGAgJ615sURY81-h1wGOkpciygqPccLcxFFe7I03H3B9RPokzVh3FxT2Qp8BZ9gNrrw_Rj6ruYyHRS8Flh8XGrEJhHJ8ncIbfiY0gNli_V9y78JOJ04oXCSkRcLz11wv4ZcdhyxsNKodKpDdCXsECY8VLLjW0FWgFGnUWqCKa7nHemQ2d2ZlLj8kOmv1VtZAyKZU2ViHsTDbHNseGFs82FMqsN7R8IqLl_yFaPhHRo4Z6RJ-9TOgVVoZIGW4Dt_ZC73D_ttoYeYf5fAesqDnLDpApjmeaNkk-qHY-FMFJ2hcByNH2sckXRIUK8FFUTsds2Bfwg0DvNdxxaG5EZaCkbV0jxUcXr8l4z-pnszDdKYXbTTy-wp88hjt8gDt8Au6ww90BeA76b_oIhMkX5rB8AoflF-MQPocDQtvg2Y8gLRbZnVsnhxcpuXPp7Zv8tTmYJhYw3-uapf2BoSp4BbesaLFksZUSAYFxkplIqYilYaTwqBOSFVBgwzd27pD2xmltrjgdeNSOsPX0XX2eqlZqz6edmNY8EzqyfQRetzI7GDPofmOdB-a582utnZlOP5cFq6_w4PNeBQ_8-n7HC7kKie0SZxp5wBmhwAFi6Fai2bDsmqWYF28fwMGP4LQzsW3jjTDE-wRmY1DxIfFhtYJF51HXB9zyBUVPZDjrlFuMkR12vDtV4zGcMszo8hIKhWGmwNjPtitgiohonAzVGVwHNxTzcQwHq54tXGosQ9x8bETLMRtxTFYEcO0DGR8JrwO4eSAUJBwZoitVEsOJA1snINBzVlVcZjSEjIBQvIjEngjE5BbtJUN-qLhcjWvXyU47Lhmndpq3MqXQmGoJ3Pzk7suAOm1gynoyofmVNO_zCANp_Ofk31j4YOqfxtTGy91W1ybkGnvwgi-Nvib9BodHnnnGXJzTRHCZHA0E-fSepltPN370ch7mH-Dvv-DejLpGdmFkmNApwkerm9FBc-l8r9G1HVfnGAgqKZfR2eL87OxlAOaG-bxZ0dOlLRO-r3CExqVSSZpn1PYa3z2_r5qB8HCa6XPUJDbeeABrcPan-aybS4ymo9wl1S6iyj_3xzXlYOBgQTiioyrpIVoX_Tea4441WdNwM-hbKCu31MYsH2XC8MFI8MPKJNCFsKoFVmqX0gDy-WYjWck3G6wb-3H6m3xjfoWiaUD_A_NbXje4fXz7Y-T-j7r_pH8B)):

```py
from timeit import default_timer as time
from itertools import accumulate
import itertools
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import deque
from itertools import repeat
from operator import add
import heapq
import random
import sys


def Kelly(A):
    return max(map(sum, zip(
        accumulate(A, max),
        A[2:],
        [*accumulate(A[:3:-1], max)][::-1]
    )))


def Kelly2(A):
    def max2(a, b):
        return b if a < b else a
    return max(map(sum, zip(
        accumulate(A, max2),
        A[2:],
        [*accumulate(A[:3:-1], max2)][::-1]
    )))


def Kelly3(A):
    def accumax(A):
        max = float('-inf')
        return [
            (max := a) if a > max else max
            for a in A
        ]
    left = accumax(A)
    middle = A[2:]
    right = accumax(A[:3:-1])[::-1]
    return max(map(add, map(add, left, middle), right))


def For(A):
    n = len(A)
    
    dp = [[0] * n for i in range(4)]

    dp[1][0] = A[0]          # The best of picking 1 element up to the 1st is the 1st.
    dp[2][0] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 2 elements up to the 1st.
    dp[2][1] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 2 elements up to the 2nd.
    dp[3][0] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 3 elements up to the 1st.
    dp[3][1] = -float('inf') # You cannot pick 3 elements up to the 2nd.
                             # Theoretically up to 4th, but the `for` already does it for you.
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        dp[1][i] = max(
                    dp[1][i-1], # Either we skip the current
                    A[i]        # Or we choose it
                    )

    for i in range(2, n):
        dp[2][i] = max(
                    dp[2][i-1],       # Either we skip the current
                    A[i] + dp[1][i-2] # Or we choose it
                    )

    for i in range(2, n):
        dp[3][i] = max(
                    dp[3][i-1],       # Either we skip the current
                    A[i] + dp[2][i-2] # Or we choose it
                    )

    max_sum = dp[3][n-1]
    
    return max_sum


def VPfB(A):

    # extract up to top 7 values and their indices in the original list
    with_indices_gen = zip(A, itertools.count()) # credit: Kelly Bundy
    top_values, top_indices = zip(*heapq.nlargest(7, with_indices_gen))

    # define a tiny helper:
    def is_adjacent(x, y): 
        return abs(top_indices[x] - top_indices[y]) == 1

    # try all valid combinations (worst case 35 loop iterations)
    sums = []
    for i,j,k in itertools.combinations(range(len(top_values)), 3): 
        if is_adjacent(i, j) or is_adjacent(j, k) or is_adjacent(i, k): 
            continue
        sums.append(sum(top_values[x] for x in [i, j, k]))

    # and choose the best
    return max(sums)


funcs = Kelly, Kelly2, Kelly3, For, VPfB

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

for _ in range(25):
    A = random.choices(range(-10**6, 10**6), k=10**5)
    expect = none = object()
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        result = f(A)
        times[f].append(time() - t0)
        if expect is none:
            expect = result
        else:
            assert result == expect

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution takes O(N^3) time, which seems like a waste. If you sort the list while keeping the original index of each number (takes O(NlogN) time), you can then find the right sum easily.

If by chance the first three numbers are not adjacent, you're done - just sum the first three numebrs. They may be adjacent so you need to look for other alternatives. However, you are guaranteed to find 3 non adjacent numbers in the first seven elements of the array, so you just need to look at all options to take 3 numbers out of the first 7 - that's 7 choose 3 options (35) - no matter how long your list is.

That way you find the sum with a time complexity of O(NlogN), which is better than O(N^3).

Actually you can do better, we don't need the entire list sorted, just the 7 largest numbers, so find them. It takes O(N) to find the maximum, and you need to do it 7 times - so in O(7*N + 35), which is O(N) you can find the sum.

Comment: Where does the + 10 in O(5*n + 10) come from?

Comment: Finding the 5 greatest numbers is not enough. Take, for example, `[7,100,7,100,7,1,1,1]`. If you took only the 5 greatest, you'd then have to choose the non-adjacent 7, 7, 7 as the result, but the best solution is 201.

Comment: 10 is 5 choose 3 - finding the best triplet.

Comment: Oh, so maybe we need to take 6 or 7, not sure, but it doesn't change anything major - the complexity remains O(N)

Comment: When you just say "sort", it is understood as ascending. And then the "first" numbers are the *smallest* ones, not what we want here. (Btw your edit overlooked the "five")